# Hide the pdf source in google viewer

Tags: php

I use Google viewer to show pdf on webpage.

http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.google.com%2Farchive%2Fbigtable-osdi06.pdf

My client wants to hide the source of url i.e If view source a html page, it shows the path of the file.

Please help me, is any way to pass the url by php or any other ideas?

Comment: You can use your server to "proxy" the PDF to Google Viewer, so to "hide the original source". But as deceze points out, people can save the PDF anyway.

Comment: @Passerby If the URL is embedded in the HTML itself, proxying will hardly help.

Comment: @deceze OP has a server, I assume he can control the webpages on it, so he can change every PDF link to `http://site.com/pdf/?id=12345`.

Comment: @Passerby Yes.....? How is he going to use Google's Viewer then? Google's Viewer embeds the URL somewhere in its code, which is the concern. Either you're using Google's Viewer, which will embed the URL in its code to do its work, or you're not.

Comment: @deceze I mean `http://google/viewer?url=encode(http://site.com/pdf/?id=12345)`, so visitors always see the "proxied" url. I wonder if that's enough to please the money payer...

Comment: @Passerby I see, so you're just proxying the PDF's URL, not the Viewer itself. Still, then `http://site.com/pdf/?id=12345` will be *a* URL to download the PDF from. It just aliases the URL, it doesn't hide it.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a working sample

Comment: It might help if you explain why your boss wants to hide the origional url!

Comment: @TobyAllen to prevent from direct accessing a pdf

Comment: @Tamil And *why* does he want to prevent people from accessing the PDF?

Comment: Tamil if google can get your pdf so can anyone else.  The only way would be to have an expiring url to give google that works for a short period of time and then won't work, but google is just another web user in this instance.

Comment: @deceze By proxying the PDF's URL, one _could be_ able to implement some restriction on the proxy application, e.g. only allow access from Google IP range...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not unless you create your own PDF viewer that supports some sort of hidden passing of the PDF's identity or URI. Google's viewer lets you *save the original PDF* under the File menu anyway. I have no idea what your client is concerned about or is trying to hide.

Answer (score 2):

Since google viewer converts all pages to images, all you'll have to do is fetch thoose images with php and the show them with/however you want to display them. Be it a slider or just a table with all the pages. But I suspect it may be a breach of ToS.

**Here is some sample code:**

```
<?php
//Share the document first so it's saved then its id won't be changed making it alot easier for us to get the images, make sure its public aswell
$url = 'https://docs.google.com/file/d/someweirdid/edit?usp=sharing';//the url for the file
$urlexp = explode('/', $url);
end($urlexp);
$id = prev($urlexp);
//here you cant print the image as is or read it with php and use your own domain to output it
$image = "https://docs.google.com/file/d/".$id."/image?pagenumber=1&w=800";
echo "<img src='".$image."' />";
/* Code to print it on ur own domain as your own
$im = file_get_contents($image);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $im;
*/
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

In this instance Google is simply another web user accessing your PUBLICLY available pdf.

The only option to prevent direct access to your PDF url is to have a temporary url that expires either after a specific number of uses or time

eg.

Use PHP to generate a unique url to the pdf

```
http://example.com/pdfs/importantpdf.pdf?id=2342oiuqer23413;ja;sekfj;kjewr
```

Only return the pdf from your server if the id is correct and still available by count or time.  This way you do not need to expose the actual file name on your server, but your pdf can be served if you want.  You could also try only returning the pdf if google is requesting it, but this may be non-trivial and error prone.

But as pointed out by others Google pdf viewer (in fact any pdf viewer) will allow you to save the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you could do is have a different URL pass the PDF, but only if the request comes from docs.google.com.

So you'd have a site e.g. www.mypdfserver.com and when someone calls a PDF you check if the request is from docs.google.com. If so you redirect to the original URL. If not not you serve nothing.

Comment: 1) That's pretty easy to spoof and 2) I don't really think the request will be coming from the web browser, but rather from some backend Google server, which means it probably won't have any referer. Not sure about how exactly the Google Viewer works though.

Comment: ad 1) TRUE - but what you gonna do? IMHO the request is flawed in that sense. ad 2) The Google server definitely has an IP range you can check for. In that case you'd use $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] instead of HTTP_REFERER.

Comment: Fair enough. That still means the user can *see* the URL in the source and even *get* the PDF through a menu item in the Viewer itself. You've only disabled the case of someone examining the source code and trying to download the PDF directly from the source. It neither hides the URL nor the PDF. Is that worth it? :)